# How to get all the first elements in a 2D list array?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a 2D list array which I declared as -

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> seqList;
seqList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

and the list contains the following elements -

```
[Mod5], [Mod5], [Mod5]
[Mod5, Mod10], [Mod5, Mod10]
[Mod5, Mod10, Mod8], [Mod5, Mod10, Mod8], [Mod5, Mod10, Mod8]
```

I want to extract the first elements of all the rows and save it in another list i.e. The result should be 
    `[Mod5], [Mod5, Mod10], [Mod5, Mod10, Mod8]`
 Is there a possible way to do that?

Comment: a for loop?  or am I missing something

Comment: In the "following elements" you quote, it's not clear which are strings and which are lists.  (The samples you've provided _appear_ to be lists of lists of lists, not lists of lists.)

Comment: It is a list if lists. And I need the answer as a list of lists too...which is `[Mod5], [Mod5, Mod10], [Mod5, Mod10, Mod8]`

Comment: This makes no sense, Swetha. Extracting the first element of each member of a `List<List<String>>` produces a `List<String>` and **not a list of lists**.

Comment: Each member of the `List<List<String>>` is a `List<String>` of course. I need all the first elements of all the rows into a list which then makes it into a `List<List<String>>` right?

Answer (score 6):

Of course there is - a simple loop would do the trick:

```
ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
for (ArrayList<String> s : seqList)
    res.add(s.get(0));
```

Note that the above code assumes that the lists are not empty. If that assumption is not true, add a check for an empty list before getting the initial element.

Comment: I want to access the complete list of elements like-   '[Mod5], [Mod5, Mod10], [Mod5, Mod10, Mod8]' into my result list and then access the individual elements later on.

Comment: @SwethaP Since these are strings, you would need to additionally parse them. You can use `String.split` for that - e.g. `String[] tokens = str.split("[\\][, ]");`

Comment: could you explain it to me in more detail? the loop mentioned above is giving me the base entries i.e. it's giving me `[Mod5], [Mod5], [Mod5]`

Comment: @SwethaP Could you update your question to show the code that produced the output, and also the result that you would expect?

Comment: I have edited the question now. I think it's clearer than the earlier version

Comment: @SwethaP This is precisely what I'd expect you to get by running the piece of code from the answer. Are you sure that your original list is a list of lists and not a list of lists of lists? In other words, is `[Mod5, Mod10, Mod8]` a single `String` containing `"[Mod5, Mod10, Mod8]"`, or a list of three strings `"Mod5"`, `"Mod10"`, and `"Mod8"`?

Comment: Yes. It is a list of three strings containing `"Mod5"`, `"Mod10"` and `"Mod8"` Sorry about the confusion if the post isn't clear

Comment: @SwethaP So is `seqList` an `ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>` then?

Comment: No. It is just `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

Comment: @SwethaP How is it subdivided in three groups corresponding to the three lines in your list of elements then? I mean first group:`[Mod5], [Mod5], [Mod5]`, second group:`[Mod5, Mod10], [Mod5, Mod10]`, and third group:`[Mod5, Mod10, Mod8], [Mod5, Mod10, Mod8], [Mod5, Mod10, Mod8]`?

Comment: `public void removeDuplicates()`
  `{`
    
    `for ( int i = 0; i < seqList.size(); i++ )`
    `{`
       `for ( int j = 0; j < seqList.size(); j++ )`
       `{`
          `if ( i == j )`
          `{`
            `// i & j refer to same entry so do nothing`
          `}`

          `else if ( seqList.get( j ).equals( seqList.get( i ) ) )`
          `{`
           `seqList.remove( j );`
          `}`
       `}`
   `}`
  `}`

Comment: @SwethaP This is not quite "extracting first rows" though, because the rows in your example are not really "rows", they are groups of identical items which you needed to remove :)